# Bash - split result of a command on ": " and call a program with the first part

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I use the following command to search for text within files in a set of folders:

```
#    get a list of files     get the contents           find the search string and        don't show any results
#                                                           print the line number          where the line is more than 400 chars
#          |                        |                             |                               |
#          v                        v                             v                               v
find app public/javascripts | awk '{print "\""$0"\""}' |xargs grep -n "new_pupil_group_form" | awk 'length($0) < 400'
```

this all works fine:  i get results like this, which is just what i want to see.

```
app/views/cmw/pupil_groups/index.html.erb:65:  <%= render :partial => "cmw/pupil_groups/new_pupil_group_form" %>
app/views/cmw/pupil_groups/edit.html.erb:52:  <%= render :partial => "cmw/pupil_groups/new_pupil_group_form" %>
app/views/cmw/pupil_groups/create.js.rjs:9:  page.replace_html "modal-new-class", :partial => "cmw/pupil_groups/new_pupil_group_form"  
app/views/pupil_groups/_class_modals.html.erb:2:  <%= render :partial => "cmw/pupil_groups/new_pupil_group_form" %>
```

I like getting the line number because i can call my favoured text editor (geany) with the file and line number and it opens focussed that line:

```
geany app/views/cmw/pupil_groups/index.html.erb:65
```

Sometimes i want to pass all the results of my search into geany, ie open all the files in the results.  What should i add to the end of my command to make this happen?  I think the solution involves splitting the result on ": " (note the space) and using the first part, and i've tried to do this with awk but can't manage it.

thanks, max

Comment: If you want to open the files containing the match, then you could use `grep -l`.  The `-l` option would list matching files.

Comment: So, if you start geany like this, would it do what you want? `geany "file1:65" "file2:34" "file3:28"`

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes - with or without the quotes.

Comment: @devnull - that works (changing my `grep -n` to `grep -l` then adding `| xargs geany` to the end) but i lose the line numbers.

Comment: If all you want is the line numbers, then pipe the output to `awk -F': ' '{print $1}'`

Comment: Adding this `| awk -F': ' '{print $1}'  |xargs geany ` does it - thanks!

Comment: BTw @devnull if you put that in an answer i'll mark it correct.

Comment: Just so you know, I've just added to my answer so that the original behaviour can be reproduced as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do this in `awk`:

```
geany $(find public/javascripts/ -type f -exec awk '/new_pupil_group_form/ && length($0) < 400 { printf FILENAME":"FNR" "}' {} \;)
```

This matches all lines containing `new_pupil_group_form` with length `< 400` as above and prints them. I am using `printf` so that the output is all on one line. `FNR` resets for every input file so the correct line numbers are given.

#### public/javascripts/a

```
line 1
new_pupil_group_form blah blah blah
line 2
```

#### public/javascripts/c

```
line 1
line 2
new_pupil_group_form
line 4
```

#### command

```
geany public/javascripts/a:2 public/javascripts/c:3
```

---

You can reproduce the original behaviour by slightly modifying the script:

```
find public/javascripts/ -type f -exec awk '/new_pupil_group_form/ && length($0) < 400 { print FILENAME":"FNR": "$0}' {} \;
```

#### output

```
public/javascripts/a:2: new_pupil_group_form blah blah blah
public/javascripts/c:3: new_pupil_group_form
```

Comment: I get this error: `awk: (FILENAME=public/javascripts/application.js FNR=680) fatal: cannot open file \`public/javascripts/audio' for reading (Is a directory)`

Comment: @Max My limited test case had no directories. I have edited to use `find`, so only files will be matched. As a side-effect, the search is now recursive.

Answer (score 1):

you probably want first to split the string using colon as separator and
then to compose from that the input you want :

```
echo "foo:25: bar " | awk -F ':' '{print $1":"$2}'
```

will print

```
foo:25
```

so the full command would be:

```
find app public/javascripts | awk '{print "\""$0"\""}' |xargs grep -n "new_pupil_group_form" | awk 'length($0) < 400' | awk -F ':' '{print $1":"$2}'  | xargs geany
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
geany $(find . -type f -exec grep -Hn -m1 new_pupil {} \; | awk -F: '{print $1":"$2}')
```